# How to display element Tuple int,int in loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I store data in Tuple structure:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, object> data = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, object>();
```

I fill data like as:

```
for (int i = 1; i < range.RowCount() + 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < range.ColumnCount() + 1; j++)
                {
                    data.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j), ws.Cell(i, j).Value);
                }
            }
```

Now I try to display each field from `data` excepting first row:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < data.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < data.Count + 1; j++)
                {
                    data[i, j];
                }
            }
```

How to do that?

Comment: Your key in dictionary is `Tuple<int, int>`, so you cannot get value by `int` key like as `data[i]`

Comment: I have `data` as matrix Excel. I need to avoid first row(header) and get each fields value.

Comment: You can create `Dictionary` with custom `EqualityComparer` and try to acces value like as `data[new Tuple<int,int>(i,j)]`

Comment: Do you have a compile time exception in this row `data[i, j];`?)

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use a dictionary? It looks like you'd be better of with a two-dimensional object array (`object[,]`)

Comment: You mean to create new dictionary?

Comment: I mean, why are you using `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, object>` instead of `object[,]`?

Comment: Can you share how to use object for matrix? May be I was wrong in choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong tool for the job. It would be much easier using a two-dimensional array:

```
var data = new object[range.RowCount() + 1, range.ColumnCount() + 1];

for (int i = 1; i < range.RowCount() + 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < range.ColumnCount() + 1; j++)
    {
        data[i, j] = ws.Cell(i, j).Value;
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < data.GetLength(0) + 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < data.GetLength(1) + 1; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data[i, j]);
    }
}
```

(I kept your 1-based indexing, though I think it'd be more intuitive to use 0-based then decrementing the Excel index when accessing the array)

Comment: Thank you, tell please how to declare object as public in class? like this: `Object data = new object[,];`

Comment: `public Object[,] Data;`. You can't initialize it before knowing the size

Comment: Then I can not use this way, because I have two method, one fills and another displayes.

Comment: This `var data = new object[range.RowCount(), range.ColumnCount()];` fills object by null otherwise if there are not data

Comment: I don't see how that's an issue. You can't display the data before initializing anyway, so return null when the method to fill the data hasn't been called yet

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider. Is when you use an object as a key in your dictionary, if it's not a primitive or string object, you need the same instance to retrieve the value. Or implement your equals method to check if the given instance is equals to a known key as @George Alexandria commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875541/how-to-display-element-tuple-int-int-in-loop#comment76729627_44875541). That is did internally with primitive and string keys. 
You also can try to loop over the key set stored in the dictionary.

The second wrong thing is trying to retrieve the value with 2 keys. You need to pass the object instance containing i, j and not i, j. Should be as next:

> data[new Tuple(i, j)];

And not:

> data[i, j];